# Ruby and Rails: Statement Modifiers in Views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

I have this code

```
<% if approved %>
  <td>Flow Number</td>
<% end %>
```

and I'd like to shorten it using statement modifiers. Of course I can use

```
<%="<td>Flow Number</td>" if approved -%>
```

**but is there a shorter way? I'd also like to get the markup out of quotes.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use "content_tag", which isn't actually shorter, but may be more appealing, keeping HTML out of your ruby blocks:

```
<%= content_tag :td, "Flow Number" if approved %>
```

Otherwise, you could consider writing a helper - which may be appealing if you need to reuse similar logic throughout the page (or over several pages).

Comment: Thanks for that, Neil. More options is/are what I'm looking for. I'll have to look into the content_tag a bit more. We use it to insert content from a page to a template, but not in the way you have it here. Might be nice.

Comment: Whoops, I meant we use content_for. I didn't know about content_tag, that's nice.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/)?

That'd be:

```
- if approved?
  %td Flow Number
```

Not exactly what you're after I know.

Comment: Always interested in new stuff, even if I end up deciding it's junk. I'll check it out, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think a helper method using content_tag internally would be the best short way.
Using a helper method, you could also yield to the desired output like this:

```
# in view helper
def show_if(condition, wrapper_tag)
  condition ? content_tag(wrapper_tag, yield) : ''
end

# in view
<%= show_if(approved, :td) {'Flow Number'} %>
```

or

```
# in view helper
def show_if(condition)
  condition ? yield : ''
end

# in view
<% show_if(approved) do %>
  <td>Flow Number</td>
<% end %>
```

I like this last method for a nice generic way to show or hide whole blocks based on a condition. Hope that helps!